# How to change background color html attribute using thymelaf?

Tags: html, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I'm trying in a web application to change the background color with a specific value from the model.

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem; background: [[${task.color}]]" >
</div>
```

where task.color is a string value of a default html color choosed from the model but this way doesn't work.

How can I change the background color with a color set from the model on the given DIV?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want Thymeleaf to process attributes, you must prefix them with `th:`.

```
<div class="card" th:style="|width: 18rem; background: ${task.color}|">
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" th:styleAppend="|background: ${task.color}|">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Metroids, the second solution it's exactly what I was looking for.